# Use FILTER() inside Foreach loop - PHP Goutte

Tags: php, symfony, goutte

I have this code

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p class="message">Hello World!
        <span>This is span</span>
        </p>
        <p>Hello Crawler!
                <span>This is span</span>
    </p>
    </body>
</html>
HTML;

$crawler = new Crawler($html);

foreach ($crawler->filter('body') as $domElement) {
   $domElement->filter('span');
}
```

I am getting this error .

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::filter()
```

I need to know how do I select elements using `CSS Selectors` inside that Foreach loop?

I searched a lot but did not find anything.

Answer (score 9):

just use the example you've in the [docs](https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler/blob/master/Crawler.php#L351)

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);

$crawler->filter('body')->each(function(Crawler $node, $i){
    return $node->filter('span');
});
```

or doing the work that the `->each(\Closure $closure)` function does under the hood: *instantiating the crawler nodes inside the loop*

```
foreach ($crawler->filter('body') as $domElement) {
    $domElement = new Crawler($domElement);
    $domElement->filter('span');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The error is on this line:

```
$domElement->filter('span');
```

The reason is that *$domElement* is not of the *Crawler* class, and thus does not know the *filter* method.

There are many ways to solve this.

You could for instance, target the `span` tags directly:

```
foreach ($crawler->filter('span') as $spanElement) {
   // do something basic with $spanElement
}
```

or apply the second filter on the return value of the first filter (which is again a *Crawler* instance):

```
$crawlerBodies = $crawler->filter('body');
$crawlerSpans = $crawlerBodies->filter('span');
```

or use `filterXPath`:

```
$crawlerSpans = $crawler->filterXPath('//span');
```

or convert a *DOMElement* object back to a *Crawler* object:

```
foreach ($crawler->filter('body') as $domElement) {
    $domElement = new Crawler($domElement);
    $domElement->filter('span');
}
```